# How to filter rows in pandas by regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to cleanly filter a dataframe using regex on one of the columns.

For a contrived example:

```
In [210]: foo = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b' : ['hi', 'foo', 'fat', 'cat']})
In [211]: foo
Out[211]: 
   a    b
0  1   hi
1  2  foo
2  3  fat
3  4  cat
```

I want to filter the rows to those that start with `f` using a regex. First go:

```
In [213]: foo.b.str.match('f.*')
Out[213]: 
0    []
1    ()
2    ()
3    []
```

That's not too terribly useful. However this will get me my boolean index:

```
In [226]: foo.b.str.match('(f.*)').str.len() > 0
Out[226]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: b
```

So I could then do my restriction by:

```
In [229]: foo[foo.b.str.match('(f.*)').str.len() > 0]
Out[229]: 
   a    b
1  2  foo
2  3  fat
```

That makes me artificially put a group into the regex though, and seems like maybe not the clean way to go. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you're not wedded to regexes, `foo[foo.b.str.startswith("f")]` will work.

Comment: IMHO I think `foo[foo.b.str.match('(f.*)').str.len() > 0]` is a pretty good enough solution! More customizable and useful than startswith because it packs the versatility of regex in it.

Comment: this might be a bit late but in newer versions of pandas, the problem is fixed. the line `foo[foo.b.str.match('f.*')]` works in pandas 0.24.2 for me.

Answer (score 282):

Use [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) instead:

```
In [10]: df.b.str.contains('^f')
Out[10]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Comment: How can the boolean be inverted? Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998188/how-can-i-obtain-the-element-wise-logical-not-of-a-pandas-series

Comment: Is it possible to get only those rows having True?

Comment: @shockwave you should use: ```df.loc[df.b.str.contains('^f'), :]```

Comment: @shockwave Also you can just use `df[df.b.str.contains('^f'), :]`

Answer (score 57):

There is already a string handling function `Series.str.startswith()`. 
You should try `foo[foo.b.str.startswith('f')]`.

**Result:**

```
    a   b
1   2   foo
2   3   fat
```

I think what you expect.

Alternatively you can use contains with regex option. For example:

```
foo[foo.b.str.contains('oo', regex= True, na=False)]
```

**Result:**

```
    a   b
1   2   foo
```

`na=False` is to prevent Errors in case there is nan, null etc. values

Comment: I modified to this and it worked for me `df[~df.CITY.str.contains('~.*', regex= True, na=False)]`

Answer (score 28):

It may be a bit late, but this is now easier to do in Pandas by calling [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html). The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) explain the difference between `match`, `fullmatch` and `contains`.

Note that in order to use the results for indexing, set the `na=False` argument (or `True` if you want to include NANs in the results).

Answer (score 25):

Building off of [the great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884429/12268505) by [user3136169](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3136169/user3136169), here is an example of how that might be done also removing NoneType values.

```
def regex_filter(val):
    if val:
        mo = re.search(regex,val)
        if mo:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

df_filtered = df[df['col'].apply(regex_filter)]
```

You can also add regex as an arg:

```
def regex_filter(val,myregex):
    ...

df_filtered = df[df['col'].apply(regex_filter,regex=myregex)]
```

Comment: thanks, because of this I figured out a way to filter a column by arbitrary predicate.

Answer (score 21):

Multiple column search with dataframe:

```
frame[frame.filename.str.match('*.'+MetaData+'.*') & frame.file_path.str.match('C:\test\test.txt')]
```

Comment: `frame`? and `'C:\test\test.txt'`? Seems like you are answering a different question.

Comment: frame is df. its related to the same question, but it answers how to filter multiple columns('filename' and 'file_path') in one line code.

Answer (score 14):

Write a Boolean function that checks the regex and use apply on the column

```
foo[foo['b'].apply(regex_function)]
```

Comment: Add more context like and example function

Answer (score 6):

Using Python's built-in ability to write lambda expressions, we could filter by an arbitrary regex operation as follows:

```
import re  

# with foo being our pd dataframe
foo[foo['b'].apply(lambda x: True if re.search('^f', x) else False)]
```

By using re.search you can filter by complex regex style queries, which is more powerful in my opinion. (as `str.contains` is rather limited)

Also important to mention: You want your string to *start* with a small 'f'. By using the regex `f.*` you match your f on an arbitrary location within your text. By using the `^` symbol you explicitly state that you want it to be at the beginning of your content. So using `^f` would probably be a better idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `str`  slice

```
foo[foo.b.str[0]=='f']
Out[18]: 
   a    b
1  2  foo
2  3  fat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) in combination with [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
foo.query('b.str.contains("^f").values')
```

Alternatively you can also use [`startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
foo.query('b.str.startswith("f").values')
```

However I prefer the first alternative since it allows you to search for multiple patterns using the `|` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way.

Calling columns with `df.col_name` may be confusing for future you, some people prefere `df['col_name']`. Here are 2 steps for filtering your dataframe as desired. This allows to save all the rows.

1. Makes Pandas series boolean

```
df['b'].str.startswith('f')
```

2. Use that boolean series to filter your dataframe into a new dataframe

```
df_filt = df.loc[df['b'].str.startswith('f')]
```

Finally you can proceed to handle NaN values as best fits your needs.

- Pandas help on [missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) (check the propagation in arithmetic and comparison)
- Or just check if needed if some missing data slipped by. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530232/how-to-check-if-any-value-is-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe) is helpful