# How can I obtain the element-wise logical NOT of a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, operators, boolean-logic

I have a pandas `Series` object containing boolean values. How can I get a series containing the logical `NOT` of each value?

For example, consider a series containing:

```
True
True
True
False
```

The series I'd like to get would contain:

```
False
False
False
True
```

This seems like it should be reasonably simple, but apparently I've misplaced my mojo =(

Comment: It is important that the data does not contain `object` types for the answers below to work, so use: `~ df.astype('bool')`

Comment: I've written about all of the logical operators in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/4909087). The post also includes alternatives.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

To invert a boolean Series, [use `~s`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [7]: s = pd.Series([True, True, False, True])

In [8]: ~s
Out[8]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Using Python2.7, NumPy 1.8.0, Pandas 0.13.1:

```
In [119]: s = pd.Series([True, True, False, True]*10000)

In [10]:  %timeit np.invert(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.8 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit ~s
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.5 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit (-s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.5 µs per loop
```

As of Pandas 0.13.0, Series are no longer subclasses of `numpy.ndarray`; they are now subclasses of `pd.NDFrame`. This might have something to do with why `np.invert(s)` is no longer as fast as `~s` or `-s`.

Caveat: `timeit` results may vary depending on many factors including hardware, compiler, OS, Python, NumPy and Pandas versions.

Comment: Duly noted.  Other than being much slower, what's the difference between the tilde and `-` ?

Comment: Wierd, I actually tested the `tilde` as it was mentioned in the documentation, but it didn't perform the same as `np.invert` :S

Comment: @blz: At least on my Ubuntu machine, running NumPy 1.6.2, the performance of `np.invert(s)`, `~s` and `-s` are all the same.

Comment: @root: I'm not sure why there is such a great discrepancy in our timeit results, but it certainly can happen. What OS and version of NumPy are you using?

Comment: Also on Ubuntu, but using NumPy 1.7.0...(`np.bitwise_not(s)` performs the same as `np.inverse`).

Comment: @root, @unutbu,  I can confirm that `np.invert` and the `~` operator have identical performance on my machine as well:  numpy 1.6.2 on Ubuntu latest.

Comment: Where does the Pandas documentation tell about the `~` operator?

Comment: @RobertPollak: It is mentioned [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: For completeness sake, consider adding `%timeit s == False` - it's about twice as slow as the slowest contender, but it paints a more complete picture, IMHO :)

Answer (score 74):

@unutbu's answer is spot on, just wanted to add a warning that your mask needs to be dtype bool, not 'object'.  Ie your mask can't have *ever* had any nan's. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions) - even if your mask is nan-free now, it will remain 'object' type.

The inverse of an 'object' series won't throw an error, instead you'll get a garbage mask of ints that won't work as you expect.

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[True, False, np.nan], 'B':[True, False, True]})
In[2]: df.dropna(inplace=True)
In[3]: df['A']
Out[3]:
0    True
1   False
Name: A, dtype object
In[4]: ~df['A']
Out[4]:
0   -2
0   -1
Name: A, dtype object
```

After speaking with colleagues about this one I have an explanation: It looks like pandas is reverting to the bitwise operator:

```
In [1]: ~True
Out[1]: -2
```

As @geher says, you can convert it to bool with astype before you inverse with ~

```py
~df['A'].astype(bool)
0    False
1     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
(~df['A']).astype(bool)
0    True
1    True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: in your example, the output ints mask can be converted to the bool series you want with `.astype(bool)` e.g. `~df['A'].astype(bool)`

Comment: This is working because ``astype(bool)`` is happening before the ``~``
```~df['A'].astype(bool)``` vs
```(~df['A']).astype(bool)```

Answer (score 22):

I just give it a shot:

```
In [9]: s = Series([True, True, True, False])

In [10]: s
Out[10]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False

In [11]: -s
Out[11]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
```

Comment: I literally tried every operator other than `-`!  I'll keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [`numpy.invert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: s = pd.Series([True, True, False, True])

In [4]: np.invert(s)
Out[4]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
```

EDIT: The difference in performance appears on Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7, NumPy 1.7.0 - doesn't seem to exist using NumPy 1.6.2 though:

```
In [5]: %timeit (-s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.8 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit np.invert(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.85 us per loop

In [7]: %timeit ~s
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.3 us per loop
```

Comment: it may not be correct on a different platform.  Win 7, python 3.6.3  numpy 1.13.3, pandas 0.20.3,  (-s) will be the fastest, (~s) is the second, and np.invert(s) is the slowest one

Answer (score 1):

In support to the excellent answers here, and for future convenience, there may be a case where you want to flip the truth values in the columns and have other values remain the same (nan values for instance)

```py
In[1]: series = pd.Series([True, np.nan, False, np.nan])
In[2]: series = series[series.notna()] #remove nan values
 
In[3]: series # without nan                                            
Out[3]: 
0     True
2    False
dtype: object

# Out[4] expected to be inverse of Out[3], pandas applies bitwise complement 
# operator instead as in `lambda x : (-1*x)-1`

In[4]: ~series
Out[4]: 
0    -2
2    -1
dtype: object
```

as a simple non-vectorized solution you can just, 1. check types2. inverse bools

```
In[1]: series = pd.Series([True, np.nan, False, np.nan])

In[2]: series = series.apply(lambda x : not x if x is bool else x)
Out[2]: 
Out[2]: 
0     True
1      NaN
2    False
3      NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy is slower because it casts the input to boolean values (so None and 0 becomes False and everything else becomes True).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series([True, None, False, True])
np.logical_not(s)
```

gives you

```py
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: object
```

whereas ~s would crash. In most cases tilde would be a safer choice than NumPy.

Pandas 0.25, NumPy 1.17

Answer (score 0):

If your answer has any kind of `<NA>` `np.nan` or similar, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```py
inverted_series = (1 - original_series).astype('boolean')
```

It maintains your na values and successfully inverts it.