# conditionally replace part of a string in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a string if I don't have a specific delimiter/string in a column. If the delimiter already exists in that row then I don't want to touch that row. I have around 3.5million records.

Below is the sample set. I want to replace ***is*** with ***:***

```
One:1
Two:2 
Three is 3 
Four is IV:4
```

Output should be like this

```
One:1
Two:2
Three:3
Four is IV:4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it without loop and a one-liner using loc

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["One:1", "Two:2", "Three is 3", "Four is IV:4", "Five is V"], columns=["myValues"])


df.loc[~df['myValues'].str.contains(':'), 'myValues'] = df.loc[~df['myValues'].str.contains(':'), 'myValues'].str.replace('is', ':')
```

print(df)

```
    myValues
0   One:1
1   Two:2
2   Three : 3
3   Four is IV:4
4   Five : V
```

Comment: Thanks @Vaishali.
Could you please also help me with this problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984764/create-a-new-column-in-a-dataframe-if-the-column-contains-the-string-from-a-colu

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
*Inplace* with `update`

```
df.update(
    df.myValues.loc[
        lambda x: ~x.str.contains(':')
    ].str.replace('\s+is\s+', ':'))

       myValues
0         One:1
1         Two:2
2       Three:3
3  Four is IV:4
```

---

**Option 2**
*Inline and using `map`*

```
f = lambda x: x if ':' in x else x.replace(' is ', ':')
df.assign(myValues=list(map(f, v)))

       myValues
0         One:1
1         Two:2
2       Three:3
3  Four is IV:4
```

Answer (score 1):

First, filter out all strings containing `:`. Then, replace " is " with ":" for all rows left. (In your example, the space around "is" is also deleted. Thus, I replace " is " with ":".)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["One:1", "Two:2", "Three is 3", "Four is IV:4"], columns=["myValues"])
for idx, v in df[~df.myValues.str.contains(":")].iterrows():
    df.loc[idx].myValues = df.iloc[idx].myValues.replace(" is ", ":")
```

References

- [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)
- [How can I obtain the element-wise logical NOT of a pandas Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998188/how-can-i-obtain-the-element-wise-logical-not-of-a-pandas-series)

Answer (score 1):

Other than `.contains()`, you can also use simple string operations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["One:1", "Two:2", "Three is 3", "Four is IV:4"], columns=["myValues"])
target = [":" not in e for e in df.myValues]
df.myValues[target] = df.myValues[target].str.replace(" is ",":")
```

Result:

```
       myValues
0         One:1
1         Two:2
2       Three:3
3  Four is IV:4
```