# Create a new column in a dataframe if the column contains a string from a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column in my dataframe if the column contains any of the values from a column of a second dataframe.

First dataframe

```
WXYnineZAB
EFGsixHIJ
QRSeightTUV
GHItwoJKL
YZAfiveBCD
EFGsixHIJ
MNOthreePQR
ABConeDEF
MNOthreePQR
MNOthreePQR
YZAfiveBCD
WXYnineZAB
GHItwoJKL
KLMsevenNOP
EFGsixHIJ
ABConeDEF
KLMsevenNOP
QRSeightTUV
STUfourVWX
STUfourVWX
KLMsevenNOP
WXYnineZAB
CDEtenFGH
YZAfiveBCD
CDEtenFGH
QRSeightTUV
ABConeDEF
STUfourVWX
CDEtenFGH
GHItwoJKL
```

Second Dataframe

```
one
three
five
seven
nine
```

Output DataFrame

```
WXYnineZAB,nine
EFGsixHIJ,***
QRSeightTUV,***
GHItwoJKL,***
YZAfiveBCD,five
EFGsixHIJ,***
MNOthreePQR,three
ABConeDEF,one
MNOthreePQR,three
MNOthreePQR,three
YZAfiveBCD,five
WXYnineZAB,nine
GHItwoJKL,***
KLMsevenNOP,seven
EFGsixHIJ,***
ABConeDEF,one
KLMsevenNOP,seven
QRSeightTUV,***
STUfourVWX,***
STUfourVWX,***
KLMsevenNOP,seven
WXYnineZAB,nine
CDEtenFGH,***
YZAfiveBCD,five
CDEtenFGH,***
QRSeightTUV,***
ABConeDEF,one
STUfourVWX,***
CDEtenFGH,***
GHItwoJKL,***
```

To explain it easily I made the first dataframe be 3chars + search string + 3chars, but my actual file doesn't have any consistency like this.

Answer (score 0):

Source DFs:

```
In [172]: d1
Out[172]:
            txt
0    WXYnineZAB
1     EFGsixHIJ
2   QRSeightTUV
3     GHItwoJKL
4    YZAfiveBCD
..          ...
25  QRSeightTUV
26    ABConeDEF
27   STUfourVWX
28    CDEtenFGH
29    GHItwoJKL

[30 rows x 1 columns]

In [173]: d2
Out[173]:
    word
0    one
1  three
2   five
3  seven
4   nine
```

generate RegEx pattern from the second DataFrame:

```
In [174]: pat = r'({})'.format(d2['word'].str.cat(sep='|'))

In [175]: pat
Out[175]: '(one|three|five|seven|nine)'
```

extract words matching the RegEx pattern and assign them as a new column:

```
In [176]: d1['new'] = d1['txt'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)

In [177]: d1
Out[177]:
            txt   new
0    WXYnineZAB  nine
1     EFGsixHIJ   NaN
2   QRSeightTUV   NaN
3     GHItwoJKL   NaN
4    YZAfiveBCD  five
..          ...   ...
25  QRSeightTUV   NaN
26    ABConeDEF   one
27   STUfourVWX   NaN
28    CDEtenFGH   NaN
29    GHItwoJKL   NaN

[30 rows x 2 columns]
```

you can also fill NaN's if you want in the same step:

```
In [178]: d1['new'] = d1['txt'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).fillna('***')

In [179]: d1
Out[179]:
            txt   new
0    WXYnineZAB  nine
1     EFGsixHIJ   ***
2   QRSeightTUV   ***
3     GHItwoJKL   ***
4    YZAfiveBCD  five
..          ...   ...
25  QRSeightTUV   ***
26    ABConeDEF   one
27   STUfourVWX   ***
28    CDEtenFGH   ***
29    GHItwoJKL   ***

[30 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Max. 
I don't have any pattern for search strings. It's a list of strings (each string has multiple words). Search string is a substring of a column in main dataframe.

Comment: @Prasad, this is exactly what my solution is doing... Did you give it a try?

Comment: I tried. its working for the example I have given. Sorry I might have been more clear on my problem. My column contains special characters, so regular expression is failing with **Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1** error. Could you please suggest me with a different solution some thing like that uses **contains**

Comment: @Prasad You should include those edge cases in the DataFrame examples in your question.

Comment: @Prasad, please provide a reproducible data set, otherwise we will provide you a working solution which might not work well with your data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid RegEx, here is a purely list-based solution:

```
# Sample DataFrames (structure is borrowed from MaxU)
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'txt':['WXYnineZAB','EFGsixHIJ','QRSeightTUV','GHItwoJKL']})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'word':['two','six']})
# Check if word exists in any txt (1-liner).
exists = [list(d2.word[[word in txt for word in d2.word]])[0] if sum([word in txt for word in d2.word]) == 1 else '***' for txt in d1.txt]
# Resulting output
res = pd.DataFrame(zip(d1.txt,exists), columns = ['text','word'])
```

Result:

```
          text word
0   WXYnineZAB  ***
1    EFGsixHIJ  six
2  QRSeightTUV  ***
3    GHItwoJKL  two
```