# How to create boolean columns based on column values in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I have two pandas DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`, one containing the names and age of people, and the other detailing what they are studying. What is an efficient way to join the two, so that I have boolean fields of what each person is studying?

e.g. given the following

```
# df1
name  | age
------|----
John  | 24
Kelly | 49
Gemma | 18
Bob   | 29

# df2
name  | studies
------|----------
John  | education
John  | science
Kelly | science
Bob   | law
Bob   | commerce
```

How could I create the following dataframe with boolean values for each field of study?

```
name  | age | education | science | law   | commerce |
------|-----|-----------|---------|-------|----------|
John  | 24  | True      | True    | False | False    |
Kelly | 49  | False     | True    | False | False    |
Gemma | 18  | False     | False   | False | False    |
Bob   | 29  | False     | False   | True  | True     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`, then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and replace missing values only for columns from `df22`:

```
s = df2.set_index('name')['studies']
df22 = pd.get_dummies(s, prefix_sep='', prefix='', dtype=bool).max(level=0)
df = df1.join(df22, on='name').fillna(dict.fromkeys(df22.columns, False))
print (df)
    name  age  commerce  education    law  science
0   John   24     False       True  False     True
1  Kelly   49     False      False  False     True
2  Gemma   18     False      False  False    False
3    Bob   29      True      False   True    False
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much. I encountered the error `TypeError: get_dummies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'` but managed to get around it by using `df22 = pd.get_dummies(s, prefix_sep='', prefix='').max(level=0).astype('bool')` instead. Might just be an issue with my data because its not as clean as the example I gave.

Comment: @oskaboska - No, problem is your pandas version, `dtype` is implemented in `pandas 0.23.0`

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. Thanks again

Comment: @jezrael - Tried `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype('bool')` to get a **boolean** field in dataframe. With this, the boolean value is defaulted to `True`. How to default the **boolean** as `False`?

Comment: @user12379095 - Do you think `df['column_name'] = ~(df['column_name'].astype('bool'))` ?

Comment: Correct!! Thanks so much. If I may, could you please explain the code a bit?

Comment: @user12379095 - sure, it convert True to False, False to True, in another words [invert boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998188/how-can-i-obtain-the-element-wise-logical-not-of-a-pandas-series)