# How to get the most frecuent categories of a column and store the rest's count in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Imagine i have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'], 'col2': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6]})

    col1    col2
0      a       1
1      b       1
2      c       1
3      d       2
4      e       2
5      f       3
6      g       3
7      h       3
8      i       4
9      j       5
10     k       5
11     l       6
```

if i use this code:

```
df[df.col2.isin(df.groupby('col2').size().head(3).index)]
```

i can retrieve the 3 most frecuent categories in `col2`.

**EDIT**:

What i would like to do is to filter the dataframe in such a way that only the most frecuent categories of `col2` remains in `col2`. Then i would like to create dummy columns for each category, indicating how many records of the same category there are per category and per letter in `col1`.

This would be the resulting dataframe:

```
    col1    col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  rest_count
0      a         1       0       0           0
1      b         1       0       0           0
2      c         1       0       0           0
3      d         0       1       0           0
4      e         0       1       0           0
5      f         0       0       1           0
6      g         0       0       1           0
7      h         0       0       1           0
8      i         0       0       0           1
9      j         0       0       0           1       
10     k         0       0       0           1
11     l         0       0       0           1
```

How can i store a count of the rest of categories way in a newly created column `rest_count`??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is expected output DataFrame?

Comment: what is the point of replacing col2 values? what is your objective?

Comment: Hi both, give a minute, i'll edit the question

Comment: Hi again, it's done, pleas see the edit and let me know if you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#get top values
v = df.groupby('col2').size().head(3).index
#create new DataFrame by compare each value
df1 = pd.concat([(df.col2 == x).astype(int) for x in v], axis=1)
#create counter for columns names
df1.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns, 1)]
#join together with original
df = df.join(df1)
#add column for remain values
df['rest_count'] = (~df.col2.isin(v)).astype(int)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3  rest_count
0     a     1       1       0       0           0
1     b     1       1       0       0           0
2     c     1       1       0       0           0
3     d     2       0       1       0           0
4     e     2       0       1       0           0
5     f     3       0       0       1           0
6     g     3       0       0       1           0
7     h     3       0       0       1           0
8     i     4       0       0       0           1
9     j     5       0       0       0           1
10    k     5       0       0       0           1
11    l     6       0       0       0           1
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thank you very much for your answer. Could you just provide explanations about what your code is doing please?? for the sake of understanding&learning

Comment: @Miguel2488 - I hope explanation is good, if something not clear let me know. Thanks.

Comment: it seems good, i understand everything except for the `create counter for column names` line and i also would like to know what is the `~` character for? Thank you again!!

Comment: @Miguel2488 - yes, line `df1.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns, 1)]` is list comprehension with [enumerate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593) and [format](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) for join column name with numbers and `~` is for invert boolena mask `[True, False, True]` for `[False, True, False]`, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15998188)

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_top(row, df_top):
    """create extra mask column called top3
    it will be used to filter out col2 values"""

    if row.col2 in df_top:
        row['top3'] = True
    else:
        row['top3'] = False
    return row

def update_cols(row):
    """update col2 and col3 values depending on top3 value"""

    if row['top3'] == True:
        row['col3'] = None
    else:
        row['col2'] = None
    return row

# get top3 values
df_top = df.groupby('col2').size().head(3).index
df = df.apply(lambda row: check_top(row, df_top), axis=1) 

# create col3 column
df['col3'] = df['col2']

df = df.apply(lambda row: update_cols(row), axis=1)

# select the columns that you need
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, please see the edit of the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit, your answer is near to what i need, but is missing the dummies, and it produces NaN's in col3 as well as in col 2 for the values tha are in col3 but not in col2. If you could include the dummies and replace th NaN's by zeros it should be perfect. Thank you!!