# How to update column value based on multiple conditions in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe containing various product names and looks like this:

```
                                       Name  
0                            1 Enkelt (35%) 
1                          1 Klasses Bitter  
2               1 minute Urban Protect Mask  
3                       10 Years Tawny Port 
4                             100% Frugtbar  
5                       100% Klementinjuice  
6                            100% Kokosvand
7                    1000 kernerugbrød øko.
```

See this product: `1000 kernerugbrød øko.`. I am trying to put some conditions so that I remove the `oko.` from the end, and based on the Danish language rules regarding singular and plural, add either "Økologisk" (singular) or "Økologisk**e**" (plural) in front of the name. In this case, because *kernerugbrød* does not end with the letter *r*, it should be Økologisk.

So basically the idea is like this:

I have a row containing this value in the `Name` column: `1000 kernerugbrød øko.` -> I remove the `oko.`, resulting into `1000 kernerugbrød` -> I check whether the last letter is `r` or not -> Add `Økologisk` or `Økologiske` depending on the previous step -> Final string should then be: `Økologisk 1000 kernerugbrød`.

My attempt was the following:

```
text = "Økologisk "
text2 = "Økologiske "

df['test'] = df['Name'].str.contains(",?\søko.") #creating a new column containing 
                                 #booleans to check which Name contains "oko."

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r',?\søko.', "") #replacing "oko." with empty string

if df['test']: #if the Name contained "oko."
    if df['Name'].str.contains("r(\s)?$"): #checking for plural
        df['Name'] = text2 + df['Name']
    else:
        df['Name'] = text + df['Name']
```

However, I am getting this error at `if df['test']`.

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I tried using the suggestions above but none of them actually helps me with this task. Therefore, what should I do to fix my code OR how else should my code be written in order to achieve a correct solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use double [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = df['Name'].str.contains(",?\søko.") #creating a new column containing 
                                 #booleans to check which Name contains "oko."

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r',?\søko.', "") #replacing "oko." with empty string

m2 = df['Name'].str.contains("r(\s)?$")

df['Name'] = np.where(~m1, df['Name'],
             np.where(m2, text2, text) + df['Name'])
```

Comment: Awesome! I actually tried figuring if I could use np.where for this but after a while I thought that the syntax wouldn't allow me to accomplish this. Your code did the job, however. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Excuse me, is `~` an operator in pandas? I feel like asking a question about it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - It is logical AND opearator for boolean mask, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998188/how-can-i-obtain-the-element-wise-logical-not-of-a-pandas-series)