# Python: How is a ~ used to exclude data?

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, bitwise-operators, geopandas, bitwise-not

In the below code I know that it is returning all records that are outside of the buffer, but I'm confused as to the mechanics of how that is happening.

I see that there is a "~" (aka a bitwise not) being used.  From some googling my understanding of ~ is that it returns the inverse of each bit in the input it is passed eg if the bit is a 0 it returns a 1.  Is this correct if not could someone please ELI5?

Could someone please explain the actual mechanics of how the below code is returning records that are outside of the "my_union" buffer?

NOTE: hospitals and collisions are just geo dataframes.

```
coverage = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=hospitals.geometry).buffer(10000) 
my_union = coverage.geometry.unary_union 
outside_range = collisions.loc[~collisions["geometry"].apply(lambda x: my_union.contains(x))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` does indeed perform a bitwise not in python. But here it is used to perform a logical not on each element of a list (or rather pandas Series) of booleans. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998993/5768147) for an example.

Let's assume the `collisions` GeoDataFrame contains points, but it will work similarly for other types of geometries.
Let me further change the code a bit:

```py
coverage = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=hospitals.geometry).buffer(10000) 
my_union = coverage.geometry.unary_union
within_my_union = collisions["geometry"].apply(lambda x: my_union.contains(x))
outside_range = collisions.loc[~within_my_union]
```

Then:

1. `my_union` is a single (Multi)Polygon.
2. `my_union.contains(x)` returns a boolean indicating whether the point `x` is within the `my_union` MultiPolygon.
3. `collisions["geometry"]` is a pandas Series containing the points.
4. `collisions["geometry"].apply(lambda x: my_union.contains(x))` will run `my_union.contains(x)` on each of these points.
   This will result in another pandas Series containing booleans, indicating whether each point is within `my_union`.
5. `~` then negates these booleans, so that the Series now indicates whether each point is **not** within `my_union`.
6. `collisions.loc[~within_my_union]` then selects all the rows of `collisions` where the entry in `~within_my_union` is `True`, i.e. all the points that don't lie within `my_union`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the actual mechanics and it's hard to know for sure without seeing input and output, but I had a go at explaining it below if it is helpful:

All rows from the **geometry** column in the **collisions** dataframe that contain any value in **my_union** will be excluded in the newly created **outside_range** dataframe.