# Is there a way to change True to False in python?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I would like to change so `True = False` or more exact change so `True = 0` and `False = 1` is there a way to do this?

I have a `dataframe` and would like to `df.groupby('country',as_index=False).sum()` and see how many `False` values there is in each country

I have tried `df['allowed'] = --df['allowed']` (allowed is the column with `True` and `False` values) to swap them but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe using the not operator

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998188/how-can-i-obtain-the-element-wise-logical-not-of-a-pandas-series) had the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping booleans is easy with `df["neg_allowed"] = ~df['allowed']`

Answer (score 0):

```
# we can use map method to change values directly 

df['allowed'] = df['allowed'].map({True: 0, False: 1})

#Before:   allowed      --->  #After:     allowed
            True                         0
            False                        1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
s1 = pd.Series([True, True, False, False])
```

output(`s1`):

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**Code**

True -> 0 & False -> 1

```
1 - s1
```

result:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int32
```