# Pandas - filter and regex search the index of DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame in which the columns are MultiIndex and the index is a list of names, ie `index=['Andrew', 'Bob', 'Calvin',...]`.

I would like to create a function to return all rows of the dataframe that use the name 'Bob' or perhaps start with the letter 'A' or start with lowercase. How can this be done?

I looked into the `df.filter()` with the regex argument, but it fails and I get:

```
df.filter(regex='a')
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

or:

```
df.filter(regex=('a',1)
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I've tried other things such as passing `re.compile('a')` to no avail.

Comment: Same problems, nothing new

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex

Comment: In that example they are filtering the column, the index defaults to [0,1,2,3]. My index is a list of names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try a different approach by using list comprehension and .ix:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(4),index=['Andrew', 'Bob', 'Calvin','yosef'])

df.ix[[x for x in df.index if x=='Bob']]

df.ix[[x for x in df.index if x[0]=='A']]

df.ix[[x for x in df.index if x.islower()]]
```

Comment: Thanks this answers what I was asking. Any idea if anyone uses `df.filter`? It would be nice to see some examples. This is nice, but then I need to separately handle searching the columns making my code less concise

Answer (score 10):

So it looks like part of my problem with `filter` was that I was using an outdated version of pandas. After updating I no longer get the `TypeError`. After some playing around, it looks like I can use `filter` to fit my needs. Here is what I found out.

Simply setting `df.filter(regex='string')` will return the columns which match the regex. This looks to do the same as `df.filter(regex='string', axis=1)`.

To search the index, I simply need to do `df.filter(regex='string', axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

How about using pandas.Series.str.contains(). The function works in both series and index if your index is confined to the string. Boolean for non-string becomes nan.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(4),index=['Andrew', 'Bob', 'Calvin','yosef'])
mask = df.index.str.contains(rf"^A")
columns = df.index[mask]  # columns = Index(['Andrew'], dtype='object')
```