# useing regular expression for column filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` that contains a year and a title. Some of `rows.name` are `Batman`, `Catman` etc. I am trying to get all rows of the format `.*man`, using the following expression:

```
t[t.title & re.search(r'.*man', t.title)]
```

This Fails. Is there an idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

```
t[t.title & (t.title[-3:] == 'man')]
```

Comment: great; this will work ; but I may want put a complex regular expression and I want work around match object  is there an operator like ~ or re_match ?

Comment: Use a function :
`def select_(t): return t.title[-3:] == 'man'` then t[t.title & select_(t)].
When you will need a more complex selection, just change select_

Comment: means select_t() : must return True or False ? correct .

Comment: I do not know how your DF lib (panda i assume) is working. I just replace my solution in your code. if a bool is expected, yes.

Answer (score 2):

use [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):
`df[df['title'].str.contains('.man')]`.

Comment: This will not work as 'mangggggggg' will be selected thus not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

following solution worked

```
df.ix[[x for x in df.index if re.search(r'.*e.*', x)]]
```

Inspired from || by [Pandas - filter and regex search the index of DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638377/pandas-filter-and-regex-search-the-index-of-dataframe)