# regex findall for numbers

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'm trying to extract 6-digit numbers embedded within texts. The numbers always start with a zero, are always 6 digits long separated by a period after the 4th digit, like so:

`0       0133.02[text] in location [texttext](text)      numbers
1       0121.08[text] in location [texttext](text)      numbers
...`

I run the following:

`import re
filtered = re.findall("0\d\d\d[.]\d\d", str(df['col']))`

There are 478 rows to be parsed, and each row contains the said number. However, the `filtered` result only ever outputs 60, even if I change the regex format. Interestingly, `filtered` seems to be comprised mostly of numbers from first and last few rows of the 478 rows, but not from the middle?

EDIT:
I extracted the rows that work vs don't work, and found that the ones that DO work are the first & last 30 rows (0-29, 448-477).

Here's a sample of the rows that do not work (446, 447):

`446      0005.00 [CT] in Vancouver [CMA] (B.C.)        44160
447      0170.05 [CT] in Vancouver [CMA] (B.C.)        44006`

And a sample of the rows that do work (448, 449):

`448      0050.04 [CT] in Vancouver [CMA] (B.C.)        43995
449      0067.01 [CT] in Vancouver [CMA] (B.C.)        43989`

Comment: Hard to see what's wrong without seeing the data. Your regex should be working.

Comment: Is your question related to this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex

Comment: try `'\d+\.?\d*'` and see the count of results. Possibly some of your elements are not matching your expected format

Comment: You need to share more data for this to work. We can't guess what is wrong. How about extracting the rows that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some things to help you solve this. I will remove this as it is not an answer.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = dict(col=['texttexttext 0036.01 texttext','texttexttext 0006.21 texttext'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

re.findall("0\d{3}\.\d{2}", str(df['col'])) #Simplified your regex
```

Effectively creates:

```
['0036.01', '0006.21']
```

How about trying this:

```
re.findall("0\d{3}\.\d{2}",' '.join(df['col'].tolist()))
```

And if middle rows are not working, extract a sample, e.g., and share that with us:

```
print('\n'.join(df['col'][200:220].tolist()))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i edited the post to include sample of the rows that don't work

Comment: @eh2699 strange.. what if you do the ' '.join() function instead?

Comment: that worked!! I'm sorry but I'm new to python, can you take a moment? - what does join() do to make it work that not using that didn't?

Comment: @eh2699 tbh it was more of a guess. `str.join()` glues a list of strings together to one long string. My guess is that str(df['col']) didn't return all values.