# Use regex in python to remove some rows based on some pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a data table which some text columns. I want to delete those rows which have MN followed by some number. For instance MN 894080/901060/905034,MN 90706 etc.

```
import pandas as pd
data= [
"MN 894080/901060/905034 - a file has some text.",
"L2 BLOCK AMER] [VVol MN 941737][DU MN 934010] a file has some text",
"MN 907068 || bdheks;",
"MN#287627/901060/905034 a file has some text ",
"MN# 944179 || a file has some text",
"(MN #927427)a file has some text",
"MN 933281 - a file has some text",
"a file has some text",
" a file has some text Mnuq"]
df<-pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Final output should look like below:

```
df
  data
a file has some text
a file has some text Mnuq
```

Comment: `df.loc[~df[0].str.contains(r'MN.*\d+')]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data= [
"MN 894080/901060/905034 - a file has some text.",
"L2 BLOCK AMER] [VVol MN 941737][DU MN 934010] a file has some text",
"MN 907068 || bdheks;",
"MN#287627/901060/905034 a file has some text ",
"MN# 944179 || a file has some text",
"(MN #927427)a file has some text",
"MN 933281 - a file has some text",
"a file has some text",
" a file has some text Mnuq"]

_re_remove = re.compile('MN.*\d+')
df = pd.DataFrame(row for row in data if not _re_remove.search(row))
```