# Filter for a string followed by a random row of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a row that I would like to filter for in a dataframe.

`ch=b611067=football`

My question is I would like to just filter for the `b'611067` section.

I understand I can use the follow `str.startswith('b')` to find the start of the ID but what I am looking for is a way to say something like `str.contains('random 6 digit numberical value'`

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not familiar with pandas. if you can use regex, try a pattern like `'b[0-9]{6}'`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Is it possible to add some example data so we can reproduce a solution for you?

Comment: Hi there, i have tried 'b[0-9]{6}' and it worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex)

Comment: Try pandas.str.extract: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure (yet) how to do this efficiently in pandas, but you can use regex for the match:

```
import re

pattern = '(b\d{6})'
text = 'ch=b611067=football'
matches = re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=text)
for match in matches:
    pass # do something
```

Edit: this answer explains how to use regex with pandas:
[How to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.str` accessor to use string functions on string columns, including matching by regexp:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"foo": ["us=b611068=handball", "ch=b611067=football", "de=b611069=hockey"]})
print(df.foo.str.match(r'.+=b611067=.+'))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2     False
Name: foo, dtype: bool
```

You can use this to index the dataframe, so for instance:

```
print(df[df.foo.str.match(r'.+=b611067=.+')])
```

Output:

```
                   foo
1  ch=b611067=football
```

If you want all rows that match the pattern `b<6 numbers>`, you can use the expression provided by tobias_k:

```
df.foo.str.match(r'.+=b[0-9]{6}=.+')
```

Note, this gives the same result as `df.foo.str.contains(r'=b611067=')` which doesn't require you to provide the wildcards and is the solution given in [How to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex), but as mentioned in the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), with `match` you can be stricter.