# Removing rows that does not start with/contain specific words

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have  the following output

```
Age
'1 year old',
'14 years old', 
'music store', 
'7 years old ',
'16 years old ',
```

created after using this line of code

```
df['Age']=df['Age'].str.split('.', expand=True,n=0)[0]
df['Age'].tolist()
```

I would like to remove rows from the dataset (it would be better using a copy of it or a new one after filtering it) that does not start with a number or a number + year + old or a number + years + old.

Expected output

```
Age (in a new dataset filtered)
'1 year old',
'14 years old', 
'7 years old ',
'16 years old ',
```

How could I do?

Comment: use regex to filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex

Comment: `df['Age'].str.startswith()` is a good place to start, or `df['Age'].str.contains()`

Comment: Using `df['Age'] = [x for x in df['Age'] if not x.startswith('\d+')]` I got this AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: u cant use regex with ```startswith```, only deals with the actual data, so to speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and create a boolean mask to filter the dataframe:

```
m = df['Age'].str.contains(r'(?i)^\d+\syears?\sold')
df1 = df[m]
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
             Age
0     1 year old
1   14 years old 
3    7 years old
4   16 years old
```

You can test the regex pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/pbUBvJ/1).

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Sharma. May I ask you how to include an OR condition in m? Is it ok to do as follows: `df['Age'].str.contains(r'(?i)^\d+\syears | otherword'))` ? hank you

Comment: @Math yes that would be fine, but in that case it matches the strings like, `10 year, 20 YEARS, 30 Years, otherword,...`

Answer (score 0):

The code below looks for text that starts with an apostrophe, followed by a number, and keeps only those rows :

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')


df.loc[df.Age.str.match("\'\d+")]

            Age
0   '1 year old',
1   '14 years old',
3   '7 years old ',
4   '16 years old ',
```

Note this just restricts to apostrophe and number, @Shubham's solution covers a lot more