# Regex count and print from a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, count

I am trying to count matching `regex` in a column and print out the amount found, the code below keeps giving me **0**. I have a feeling it's not iterating through the whole column? My code is as below.

```
import re

pattern = ('/^[A-Z]{1}\d{8}$/i')
numbers = jan_df['Student Number']

iterator = re.finditer(pattern, str(numbers))
count = 0

for match in iterator:
    count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: Does `pattern = r'^[A-Za-z]\d{8}$'` work? Do you mean `df = pd.DataFrame({'Student Number':['A12345678', 'abc', 'a12345678']})` should yield `2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df.loc[df['Student Number'].str.contains(r'^[A-Za-z]\d{8}$'), :].shape[0]
```

Or, if you plan to use a more specific regex and need to make it case insensitive:

```py
df.loc[df['Student Number'].str.contains(r'^[A-Z]\d{8}$', case=False), :].shape[0]

# or

df.loc[df['Student Number'].str.contains(r'(?i)^[A-Z]\d{8}$'), :].shape[0]
```

**Notes**:

- The regex in Python is defined with string literals, not regex literals, so you cannot use `/.../i` thing, you need `...` with flags as options, or as inline flags (`(?i)...`)
- `{1}` is always redundant in regex patterns, please remove it
- `Series.str.contains` returns True or False depending if there is a match. `df.loc[df[col].str.contains(...), :]` only returns those rows where the match was found
- `Dataframe.shape` returns the dimensions of the data frame, so `.shape[0]` returns the number of rows.

**Related SO posts**

- [How to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333283/3832970)
- [How do I get the row count of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943975/3832970)
- [Regular expression works on regex101.com, but not on prod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636208/3832970).